# Make QUERY formula works when reference values are blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a query to pull ALL reports available in the referenced table but then limit down the reports when options are selected.

The formula I have so far is:

`=QUERY('Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!A:AG, "SELECT A WHERE      "&IF(COLUMN(B6)>=1,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B6,'Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""),"")&" contains 'Yes'  AND "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B7,'Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!$1:$1,0),4),"1","")&" contains 'Yes' ")`

If options are selected in the referenced fields, B6 and B7 (and I plan to add several more), then the query works great. However, I don't want to require that the fields be used, and when the field is blank, then the query should skip over this and not use it as a "WHERE" condition.

This is the final step in my sheet, so I would be SOOO grateful for any help!!!

See screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 7 times.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had to create a "Default" column in the referenced tables, and then set the blank fields to the default of Yes.

`=QUERY('Standard Report Tables'!A:CC, "SELECT A WHERE      "&IF(ISBLANK(B6)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B6,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes' AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B7)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B7,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'  AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B8)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B8,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'  AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B9)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B9,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'   AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B10)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B10,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'  AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B14)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B14,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'  AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B15)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B15,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'  AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B16)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B16,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'  AND "&IF(ISBLANK(B20)=FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B20,'Standard Report Tables'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""), "B")&" contains 'Yes'  ")`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try using the Filter function instead?

=FILTER(range, condition1, condition2...)

Comment: I am not super familiar with the FILTER function, but no matter what I do, I keep getting the following error:

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 968. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count 1.

What does that error mean?

Comment: @DavidHammond Each parameter should have the same number of rows. Usually this happens when comparing a column with a single value. In this case the fix is simple, use ArrayFormula.